# UISplitViewController inside UITagBarController iOS 7 iphone bug

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uitabbarcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I have an application with UITabBarController as root controller, inside first tab there is UISplitViewController. To make it work on iPad and iPhone I used this tutorial [Universal UISPlitViewController](http://nshipster.com/uisplitviewcontroller/). Everything seems to work greak except one thing, tab bar icon disappears on iPhone running with iOS 7. It works with iPad iOS 7/8 and iPhone iOS 8. I can't figure out why it happens, but I guess it's a bug with iOS 7. Here are sreenshots:

[image][image]

Did anyone has similar problem?

Comment: Apple says that a split view controller should always be the root view controller of your application, so you shouldn't be embedding it in anything.